# Actions on Google Console showing "Your app must have at least one action to test"

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

[image]

I am having this very weird problem which I don't understand how it happened. I have created this my own app and I added a lot of intents in it. But when I need to test this app under the simulator, I can't seem to set the Test status to active. It says that my app must have at least one action to test. I am really confused because I do have a lot of actions. Is there something that I am missing here?

Then I check the FactsApp sample which Google provided. The Test Status of that app seems to be switchable. I tried to check the settings of that app but I didn't find anything that I missed to set.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Actions SDK or API.AI? Did you submit an action package for testing?

Comment: @LeonNicholls I am using API.AI. yes, I did submit action package. But nevermind. I just discovered its a bug. Although it cannot be switched to active, but still I can test the app on a real device.

Comment: I've same problem. Did you solve it.

Comment: @Karacago Yes, please check my answer.

Comment: @finalstatic Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solved the problem by myself. It seems to happen that I created an agent in API AI console that consist of a project ID that does that match any of my current projects.

I don't know how I did that. But because I was experimenting with the projects and agents. I somehow created projects of the same name but did not link it properly with the agent that I created.

You can check the project ID of your agent under the settings of that agent. Just click on the small gear located at the left side of your agent name.

So when you create an agent, make sure that its project ID is the same as the project ID of the correct project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have at least one intent which handles the GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME event.

See the docs: https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/define-actions